# Tell visual studio to close the documents that have been deleted outside of the IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 Professional and use git with Git Extensions as a version control system. When I checkout a branch that involves different versions of the files which I'm working on, VS2010 prompt me with a message that says: "this file has been modified outside of the source editor. Do you want to reload it?" I click yes to all, and get the right version of the files. Until here everything goes as expected.

The problem comes when I checkout a branch that involves files to be deleted. Files that in that branch do not exist yet/anymore. If one of these is opened in the editor, it continues there and you can keep writing on it and then save it.

I know the files can't disappear from the project tree, because we're not keeping track of the project files (at least they get in Project File explorer an exclamation mark telling you that the file doesn't exist anymore). What I want is Visual Studio to close each file that no longer exist. Is there a way to do that? Or does someone have an idea to achive this workflow?

Closing and opening Visual Studio again does the trick, actually does exactly what I want.. But it would be good to avoid it.

Thank you

Comment: You'd certainly expect the project file to change as well.  VS will prompt you to reload the project.  The editor window automatically closes.  Make sane changes and you'll get a sane outcome.

Comment: Ok, so the trick would be to include the project file (vbproj|csproj) in the version control as well (we're not doing it actually), to let this changes happend. Right? Maybe you can post this as a solution so I can accept it as a answer, if it works.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry, I forget to notify you in my previous comment... and I'm not able to edit it now, don't know why.

Comment: I'd post an answer if only I could figure out why on Earth you wouldn't update the project.  Makes no sense to me.  Just post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @HansPassant I had it on my .gitignore because I didn't know that this file tells Visual Studio what in the project is. I thought it was like the others .suo .sln .user and so on that shouldn't be tracked. I'm pretty new at git and I'm still trying to figure out what should and what shouldn't be done. About to answer the question, I just wanted to give you the merits...that's it.

Comment: @HansPassant and that's why I'm posting here, to learn from my errors and from what others can tell me about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have forgotten to include the project file vbproj or csproj in git